# iPhone SDK location on hard drive

Tags: iphone

I attempted to reinstall the iphone sdk on my mac.  I figured the reinstallation would just override my previous installation but it seems that more hard drive space was eaten up after the second install.  Does anyone know how I can refresh my installation and start from scratch to free up all the lost space?

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser.com

Comment: As this is about a developer tool (iPhone SDK) I think it should stay here and not be moved to superuser.com, which I think is more for non-developer system stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are SDK folders for each SDK version at:

```
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

and

```
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

Answer (score 44):

Certainly at least as of Xcode 4.4, this has changed. It's now:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

and

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

Comment: Although the selected answer is correct in the context of the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/ directory; this answer with the full path is more explicit and understandable than the relative path provided in the selected answer.

Answer (score 27):

It is also possible to get the path with the `xcrun` tool. In Terminal.app type the following:

```
xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
```

and

```
xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path
```

This will have the following results:

```
$ xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk
$ xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, as the approach works independently on what Xcode version is installed. As Xcode itself uses it to manage path issues.